# Adding Blank Pages in every new grouping in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2012 and I have a Main Report with two subreports. I am looking to add a blank page after every new grouping.

For example

page 1.  Student Name: John Doe

```
 Subject: Art
```

page 2. Student Name: John Doe

Subject: Math

page 3 - Should be empty

page 4- Student Name: John William (new student)

Subject: Gym

page 5- empty page

page 6- new student etc...

I have already checked off the add a page break before and after in the tablix properties does not work.

Answer (score 1):

At what grouping level in the Tablix did you set add page break before or after?

If your report has a detail then you need to add a parent group by Student's ID and set the page break before or after that group.

UPDATE:

Select the two options below and a blank page should be inserted.

```
1. Between each instance of a group
    B. Also at the end of a group
```

Comment: in the details row group i set the page break between each instance of group that works perfect, i just need to add that blank page between students

Comment: I get it. You want an actual "blank page". Updated answer

Comment: its entering the blank page at the end of the report. It should add the blank pages everytime there is a new student name

Answer (score 0):

You have presumably a List that's grouped on the Student, correct? Just add a new row to that Tablix (a List is a tablix), making sure you select "Inside the Group", and set the dimensions of that row to match page size. That will have the desired affect.